# "Hand pose estimation in-the-wild" vs Normal hand pose estimation

Tags: machine-learning

So far I have seen several article that mention "Hand pose estimation in-the-wild" and just "Hand pose estimation." What is the difference between the two?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe linking to some of the articles (or quoting passages) would help get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Hand pose estimation" studies are sometimes done under strict conditions (well light, no occlusions, and unambiguous parsing).

[image]

"Hand pose estimation in-the-wild" is less controlled and more realistic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brian! It would've been nice if it was answered earlier, but it's not a big deal